# How to freeze ImageView Image

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

Is there an equivalent of TextView's attribute `freezesText` for ImageView?

I would like to use such attribute to keep image in the ImageView across configuration changes such as screen rotation.

Comment: For that, you have to manage Screen rotation and screen state via save instance state parameter

Comment: Why would you want to do that? In fact, that is highly advised against in Google's Best Practices. Google advises to never freeze anything (not text, not images) on config change and simply recreate the entire activity/fragment. Because everything else cannot be controlled completely since it is in collision with the natural lifecycle. You can use Glide, Picasso etc, for loading the image into ImageView, since they all use the cache, and won't recreate the resource on config change.

Comment: Yea @Slobodan Antonijević I found freezing causes unpredictable effects, especially with fragments. I now use LiveData to achieve my aim